# Gmail stop() on specific label

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created a [watch()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) on 2 different labels like **INBOX** and **SENT** for same mailbox.

Now I want to [stop()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/stop) one of the watcher. Here is what I am trying

```
     let userWatchStopAsync = util.promisify(gmail.users.stop);
        return userWatchStopAsync({
          userId: "me",
          access_token: token,
          resource: {
            labelIds: [labelId],
            topicName: `projects/${projectId}/topics/${topic}`
          }
        });
  },
```

But when I try to stop watch on **SENT**,  it stop sending notification for **INBOX** also.

Am I missing something? How to stop() on just single **label**.

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer look at the docs you linked.

The `stop()` method doesn't let you specify a request body, so ignores your `labelIds` and stops all notifications completely.

The `watch()` method on the other hand allows you to specify `labelFilterAction` parameter, with possible values `"exclude"` and `"include"`.

So use the same code you use to start the watch, specify which `labelIds` you wish to exclude from your watch and add

```
labelFilterAction: "exclude"
```

into `resource`.

Comment: What if I have created a watch() with 2 different pub-sub topics. This is like one application is created a watch on a use email id. and another application is created same watch() on same email Id. So stop() in one application will break another application. So how can this situation be handled